# Export Graphics in Mathematica with Texture

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Hello guys i've been having a problem with Mathematica 8.0.

When i export my Graphics3D to 3DS or any other format, texture is always missing. For example in the screenshot attached, [image: Screenshot], u'll see that i created a plane, texturized it and exported to 3DS then when i imported it back, there was no texture.

Is there a way i can export while preserving the texture? Thanks.

Comment: The same happens on importing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246392/importing-google-sketchup-models-in-mathematica/6251192#6251192. I don't think the current set of im/exporters can handle textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add *Elements* you can see what Mathematica is importing:

```
In[1]:= Import[test.3ds", "Elements"]

Out[1]:= {Graphics3D, GraphicsComplex, PolygonColors, 
PolygonData, PolygonObjects, VertexData}
```

This means that lots of things are discarded in the import. Things like frames, textures, bumpmaps, camera etc.

The texture filenames are linked in the 3DS-format and not included like in Mathematica notebooks.